# OneNote 2016 on O365 SharePoint in Windows 10

Tags: onenote, windows10

I don't want to use the "app" for OneNote that comes with Win10 - and in fact have removed it (see powershell removal instructions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps/win-10-how-to-disable-onenote-app-after-installing/f1192f38-c45f-4541-ba3c-67e74af20f52)). But when I want to choose OneNote 2016, not OneNote Online, to open a notebook on our (hosted on O365) SharePoint - it goes to the AppStore and gives me no other option. Yes, once I get it the first time by going dumpster diving through the file explorer and it is cached in OneNote client application I can still *get* to it, but that is very frustrating for training multitudes of new users. Any solutions? The library holding the notebooks is already set to force the client application as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling the app is an optional step here. It is important to change the default version in Windows 10 from the App to the Desktop-Application.

[There's an excellent article how to change](http://itgroove.net/oh365eh/2015/09/28/setting-onenote-desktop-as-default-version-in-windows-10/).

It is not the best solution, as "normal" users won't get this change done. [This article describes how to apply the change via GPO or SCCM](https://4sysops.com/archives/default-file-associations-in-windows-10/).

Comment: The first link is bad?

Comment: Found it though. Thought I had done that - sneaky bastards, though. They don't even give you the option unless you already have the default changed. Thank you! I was at my wits' end!

Comment: Ok, WEIRD. It worked great on a machine at home. The other PC, where I had removed the Win10 app - doesn't show OneNote2016 as an option on the list for default apps. At all. Even after I reinstalled office just in case. Could it be a 64-bit issue?

Comment: 64Bit Office? Sorry, i do not have much experience with that. It is still a good practice to work with 32Bit editions in most scenarios. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Yeah, I work with large datasets so I use 64-bit. I may have to go back though, as this is driving me nuts. Thanks!